# Update rake progress (Using AJAX if possible)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've a `rake` task running a class `Boot` in the `lib` directory inside a folder called `Database` whose `rake` code is as follows:

```
namespace :trigger do
  task :something do
    opt = ENV['OP']
    Database::Boot.new opt
  end
end
```

I'm calling this via the `system` command in the controller:

```
system "rake trigger:something OP=1 &"
```

The class invoked via `rake` task inserts records into a `MySQL` table. The catch is, I am doing a success count in the `Boot` class and I want to periodically update my view with the `Id` of the record inserted and the `success count` for starters. I've tried the following approaches but none of them worked:

1. Wrote a `setInterval()` function that constantly triggered a `submit` on the `remote form` present on the page triggering a `AJAX` call, which will render a `JS` file fetching the variable from a `cache`.
2. Tried using `Observable` : http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html
3. `Rails.cache.write` and `Rails.cache.read` didnt work!
4. Tried spawning a `thread` to run `rake` task, and tried using `thread_variable_get` and `thread_variable_set`, which didnt work either.
5. Tried writing a `helper` method which renders a `JS` snippet, and tried invoking that inside the `Boot` class by including the `ApplicationHelper` module.

I'd like to pass data from the `Boot` class to the controller which can be appended into a view via `AJAX` or by any other means. I am using `Rails 2.3.18` and `Ruby 1.8`.

Comment: you need to explain better what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: I'm keeping a count of success of the records being inserted successfully into a table in the `Boot` class. I'd like to display that count, the Id of the record being inserted, and other messages like "Success" or "Failed" to the user in the view while the `Boot` class executes in the background!

Answer (score 0):

You're shelling out the rake task in a subprocess rather than a thread. Try just invoking the rake task directly:

```
ENV['OP'] = '1'
Rake::Task.invoke "trigger:something"
```

Now the Boot class will be running in the same thread and you can call methods on it to get the data you want.

Comment: This would cause the view to be rendered after the rake task finishes its execution. And also, i tried spawning it in a different thread : `Thread.new do` "system rake trigger:something" `end`, but this didnt let me access the helper methods, and even if I did access the helper method somehow(Attempt No 5.), the render method wouldn't be available inside the `Boot` class.